# Dell XPS 9300: Virtualization option in BIOS and Wifi

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, drivers, virtual-machine

I have a Dell XPS 13 9300 with Debian 10.

I was experiencing the same issue as the user Marc on [this thread](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1834277): the laptop would hang with a blank screen before completing shutdown/reboot, forcing me to hold the power button to turn it off.

In the thread, the following solution is suggested: in the BIOS settings, under the "Virtualization" section, disable the option "VT for Direct I/O".

It did solve the shutdown problem. However, for some weird reason, after rebooting I lost my WiFi connection. Internet still works with an ethernet cable, but no wireless. After trying a couple solutions in vain, I re-enabled the VT option.

Here is the result of sudo lshw -C network (after enabling the option again):

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Killer Wi-Fi 6 AX1650i 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (201NGW)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 30
       serial: 04:33:c2:1a:68:c3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.6.0-1-amd64 firmware=48.13675109.0 Qu-c0-hr-b0-48.uc ip=192.168.1.87 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:603dbb4000-603dbb7fff
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: FWIW this happens for me only if I do a `sudo reboot` - maybe this is the same issue for me.